# Non-blocking IO solution in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, ssl, io, buffer

I'm writing a program that uses multiple SSL connections. Basically, my code has to 3 separate programs that can connect to one another and communicate through SSL sockets.

The problem I'm having is with blocking I/O. For example, my class CLAFrame.java has to be able to detect and handle input from a stream, but also be able to carry out other functions. I don't want this to block the entire program and freeze it up waiting for input (like it is now).

Here's how I had it set up.

```
 static void initializeCLAConnection(){
        try {
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
                    (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =
                    (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(3577);
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();


            InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);


            OutputStream outputstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
            BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(outputstreamwriter);


            input=bufferedreader;
            output=bufferedwriter;
            System.out.println("Connection accepted from: "+sslserversocket.getInetAddress());


         String string=null;

         //RECEIVING INPUT
         while(input.ready()){
             System.out.println("CLA receiving msg");

        // while ((string = input.readLine()) != null) {
             string=input.readLine();
             System.out.println(string);
             /*
              * HEADERS FOR INPUT RECEIVED
              * Format: VAL Ryan Smith
              * VAL - requesting validation id
        */    

             String header=null;
             String rest=null;
             header=string.substring(0, 3);
             if(string.length()>3){
             rest=string.substring(4, string.length()-1);
             }
             //perform actions based on input
             switch(header){
             case "VAL ":
                 //do something
                 requestValidationID(rest);
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
             }

         } 

        }

          //  System.out.println("Successfully established CLA server on SSL port 3577");
         catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

*Note* - Previously, I had my while loop setup as 
    while ((string = input.readLine()) != null) {

However, clearly this will block I/O until input is received. I then switched to
    while(input.ready()){
This has stopped the blocking but now my buffer (input) is not receiving anything at all when I write to the stream.

Is there a better way to do this? This program is set up as a GUI so I need the buffer to be able to receive input, but I also need to be able to simultaneously use other buttons and functions on the program without it blocking everything.

Should I make it multithreaded? A thread for reading the buffer and another for all other functions? I'm a bit confused what to try next.
Any input/advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I suggest using a framework like [Netty](http://netty.io) instead of trying to implement your own Java NIO code. It provides you all the structure for handling IO asynchronously.

Comment: You need threads: one to accept connections and one per accepted connection. And don't use `ready().`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to re-invent the wheel here. There are many non-blocking frameworks out there, all built on top of Java NIO (which provides non-blocking IO functionality in Java).

[Netty](http://netty.io/) is one such example, very fast and not the highest abstraction.

Edit: 
Considering this is a school project, and that you just need to be able to do things simultaneously, I'd say what you want isn't non-blocking code, you just want your blocking code to run in a separate thread.
See Java's [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for that.

Comment: I just spent a couple of hours reading about Netty and trying to figure it out. I would have to completely restart my whole project to use it I'm having a hard time finding how I would implement the framework. Theres no simpler way to achieve what I'm doing without wasting my entire week of coding?

Comment: I cant find any good examples for a simple app-based server/client. Everything is super complicated web-based.

Comment: I think what you should consider, is that creating non-blocking communication isn't trivial. Moreover, writing bug free code is also quite demanding. What you're getting from using something like Netty, is the assurance that it's been field tested and battle hardened. There are, however, higher abstractions that may make your life easier. Take a look at Akka.

Comment: I dont really need something is quite so tested/hardered. I'm doing this for a school project so the client/server will not matter after I turn it in. I just need the simplest way to do the following:
1) establish an SSL connection between server/client
2) be able to send data from client to server through socket, and vice versa.
3) be able to receive messages and do other functions at the same time

Comment: That seems to make more sense, thanks! So to clarify, would I be able to perhaps run my buffer used for IO in a separate thread?

Comment: Basically, yes. Multithreaded code has its own set of issues, of course, but that's a whole library of books worth of discussion.